# Volterra Operator Property

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

It can be shown that if $V(f) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ denotes the Volterra operator on $C([0,1])$, then the closed subspace $A_b = \{f : f|_{[0,b]} =0\}$ satisfies $ V(A_b) \subset A_b$, that is, $A_b$ is invariant under the Volterra operator. Is it true that $A(A_b) \subset A_b$ whenever $A$ is a bounded operator satisfying $AV=VA$?

Edit: Here's a potential solution, however, I'm not sure how to bring it full circle. Any comments would be helpful! : )

Inductively we can show the following three properties:
$$
(i) \quad V x^m = \frac{x^{m+1}}{m+1}
$$
$$
(ii) \quad V^m e = \frac{x^m}{m!}
$$
$$
(iii) \quad V^m f(x) = (x^{m-1} \star f)(x),
$$
where $e \equiv 1$ on $[0,1]$.
Applying these observations to $A$, we see that $Ax^m = (x^m \star A e)'$, the derivative of the convolution. Given $f \in C[0,1]$ and $\epsilon>0$, we can find a polynomial $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^ma_k x^k$ such that $||f-p|| < \epsilon/ \lambda$, where $\lambda > 0$ is a constant to be determined later. Then, by the triangle inequality, we must have 
$$
||Vf-Af|| \leq ||Vf-Vp|| + ||Af-Ap|| + ||Vp-Ap|| \leq (M_1+M_2) \epsilon + ||Vp-Ap||.
$$
The using linearity and a rule for differentiating a convolution, we get
$$
||Vp-Ap|| \leq m \max |a_k| ||Vx^k - Ax^k|| \leq M_3 ||V x^k - (kx^{k-1} \star Ae)||.
$$

My fight is with getting this very last estimate arbitrarily small.

Comment: You have $TV(A_b) = VT(A_b)\subseteq V(A_b)$. If $T$ is continuous, then the closure $\overline{V(A_b)}$ is invariant under $T$, which is probably $A_b$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Why is $VT(A_b)\subset V(A_b)$?

Comment: @fimpellizieri I think it's because T fixed $A_b$?

Comment: What makes sense to me is $TV(A_b)=VT(A_b)\subset T(A_b)$, so $T(A_b)$ is invariant under $V$.

Comment: Sorry, I read everything backwards. I see where you're coming from. I'll think a bit more.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri : I have no idea what I was thinking when I wrote my comment, but it may be a symptom of senility. :)

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts No worries -- we all make mistakes.

Comment: Do you think this night fail even when $T$ is bounded?

Comment: Is $T$ even linear?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri $T$ is any linear operator that commutes with $V$. I actually left out the assumption that $T$ should also be bounded, but I'm curious to see if it works in any case. If it doesn't work for a continuous one, this would be enough. But it's also possible that this statement holds for such continuous linear operator.

Comment: This would be true if there were a reasonable extension of $T$ to $L^2$. I'm not sure if there is, however.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri I actually think it may be true, but I need to reconcile one inequality. I included an overview of the idea in the question itself, but the issue is an inequality on a dense set.

Comment: Are you trying to show that $V=A$? Because that is clearly false.